# How to get acquisitions - campaigns data from google analytics api v3?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've seen similar questions in SO, but please note this is not a duplicate as this is specifically for :

1) API v3
2) Acquisitions -> Campaigns (not Acquisitions -> Adwords -> Campaigns)

I'm using the ruby gem `google-api-client`

Comment: Is this question about how to use API V3 or How to get campaign data from API V3?

Comment: How to get campaign data from v3

Comment: Actually I figured it out over the weekend. Didn't get a chance to update the answer here